# optimizing Code for inserting 27000*2 keys from plain text file to DB

Tags: php, optimization, mysqli

I need to insert data from a plain text file, explode each line to 2 parts and then insert to the database. I'm doing in this way, But can this programme be optimized for speed ?

*the file has around 27000 lines of entry*
DB structure  [unique key (ext,info)]

- ext  [varchar]
- info [varchar]

code:

```
$string = file_get_contents('list.txt');  
$file_list=explode("\n",$string);  
$entry=0;  

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'file_type');  
$sql = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO info (ext,info) VALUES(?, ?)');  

$j=count($file_list);  
for($i=0;$i<$j;$i++)  
{  
 $data=explode(' ',$file_list[$i],2);   
 $sql->bind_param('ss', $data[0], $data[1]);  
 $sql->execute();  
 $entry++;  
}   
$sql->close();  
echo $entry.' entry inserted !<hr>';
```

Comment: Depending on the specific table type, you'd probably get much better performance if you call LOCK TABLE FOR WRITE before the first insert, then unlock it again after the last insert.

Comment: But I think if it's an INNODB then then the LOCK/UNLOCK is done automatically !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the magic solution [3 seconds vs 240 seconds]

**ALTER TABLE `info` DISABLE KEYS;**

```
$db->autocommit(FALSE);
//insert
$db->commit();
```

**ALTER TABLE `info` ENABLE KEYS;**

Comment: Isn't it what dev-null-dweller wrote? Anyway if it's "magic" to you - it's only so as long as you have both (web and db) on same server. You must use both disabling keys and using `load data` instead of separate inserts; that saves a lot of time on any server configuration.

Comment: **Load data** failed actually :(

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that file contains unique pairs of ext/info, you can try to disable keys for import:

```
ALTER TABLE `info` DISABLE KEYS;
```

And after import:

```
ALTER TABLE `info` ENABLE KEYS;
```

This way unique index will be rebuild once for all records, not every time something is inserted.

To increase speed even more you should change format of this file to be CSV compatible and use mysql [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to avoid parsing every line in php.

Answer (score 2):

When there are multiple items to be inserted you usually put all data in a CSV file, create a temporary table with columns matching CSV, and then do a [LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html), and then move that data into destination table. But as I can see you don't need much additional processing, so you can even treat your input file as a CSV without any additional trouble.

```
$db->exec('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _tmp_info (ext VARCHAR(255), info VARCHAR(255))');
$db->exec("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{$filename}' INTO TABLE _tmp_info
           FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
           LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"); // $filename = 'list.txt' in your case
$db->exec('INSERT INTO info (ext, info) SELECT t.ext, t.info FROM _tmp_info t');
```

You can run a `COUNT(*)` on temp table after that to show how many records were there.

Comment: Take a look at what dev-null-dweller wrote about keys below too, speeds things up even more on such large inserts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10388069/598472

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large file that you want to read in I would not use `file_get_contents`.  By using it you force the interpreter to store the entire contents in memory all at once, which is a bit wasteful.

The following is a snippet taken from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-readfiles/):

```
$file_handle = fopen("myfile", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $line = fgets($file_handle);
   echo $line;
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

This is different in that all you are keeping in memory from the file at a single instance in time is a single line (not the entire contents of the file), which in your case will probably lower the run-time memory footprint of your script.  In your case, you can use the same loop to perform your INSERT operation.

Comment: But I think it will spin my HDD a little more, not sure :/

Answer (score 0):

If you can use something like [Talend](http://uk.talend.com/index.php). It's an ETL program, simple and free (it has a paid version).